# Question about error when saving xlsm file using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, win32com, xlwings

I want to open an xlsm file via xlwings and then edit it and save it. However, some problems arose.

If I run the code with no excel file working, or just open another excel file and do not edit the excel file, it works fine. However, if I open an Excel file and do some work, for example open a blank Excel file and enter 'test' in cell A1, and run the code, sometimes it works, but sometimes it becomes unresponsive in the third line.(wb_xl = xw.Book(copy)) In this case, the code does not jump from the third line in an unresponsive state. What makes more sense is that the code works fine in some cases.
I want to know when the code works fine in all cases.

And there is one more problem.
If this code is executed while working with another Excel, only wb_xl should be terminated. I don't want another Excel to be closed. I want to exit only wb_xl. However, when the app.quit() code is executed, all open Excels are closed. In this case, how can I close only the Excel(wb_xl) opened through the code without closing the working Excel?

```
import xlwings as xw
copy = 'C:/Users/ijung/Desktop/210919_Mk_Lot_test/210922_101test.xlsm'
wb_xl = xw.Book(copy)            #sometimes no response in this line
ws_xl = wb_xl.sheets['Main']
app = xw.apps.active
ws_xl.range('A1').value = 'test'

wb_xl.save()
app.quit()
#wb_xl.app.kill()
#wb_xl.close()
```

I also used openpyxl. However, in this part of wb_open.save(copy), an error such as xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 20, column 8 occurred. When I use xlsx, the save works fine, but when I use xlsm, an error occurs.

```
import openpyxl
wb_open = openpyxl.load_workbook(copy, read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
ws_open = wb_open.active    

ws_open.cell(1,1).value = 'test'
wb_open.save(copy)             #error 
wb_open.close()
```

As a result, the purpose of this code is to open the xlsm file by executing this code even when working with another Excel, edit and save, and close only this xlsm file.However, using multiple packages and searching multiple sites could not solve the problem.I'm under a lot of stress with this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openpyxl does not works with xlsm files that contains form objects

I think the problem is in `app.quit()` you are closing the excel instance, just use `wb_xl.close()`

```
import xlwings as xw
copy = 'C:/Users/ijung/Desktop/210919_Mk_Lot_test/210922_101test.xlsm'
wb_xl = xw.Book(copy)            #sometimes no response in this line
ws_xl = wb_xl.sheets['Main']
#app = xw.apps.active # don't needed
ws_xl.range('A1').value = 'test'

wb_xl.save()
wb_xl.close()
```

This should only close the book, take a look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045634/excel-application-window-not-closing-on-workbook-close) has insteresting answers

Comment: But when I just use wb_xl.close(), the Excel does not closed perfectly. So empty excel program remain. I want to close excel perfectly